# How do I turn off Oracle password expiration?

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle for development on my local machine. The password for a bootstrap account that I always use to rebuild my database has expired.

How do I turn off password expiration for this user (and all other users) permanently?

I'm using Oracle 11g, but I don't know if the password expiration behavior is new in 11g.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
alter profile default limit password_life_time unlimited;
```

Comment: I think the new thing in 11g is that by default, password expiration is on. When creating a new database, you are asked if you want the new, secured default or the old 10g behavior. Anyway, Randy's SQL command will switch off password expiration for all users (unless you specifically added a profile with that limit to their profile).

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to change the profile in the enterprise manager. You log on as sys/sysdba, go to Server->Profiles->Default->Edit->Password->Expire in->Unlimited.
That's it. I don't know if this will change once set Expiration Dates as well, otherwise
re-set the profile on the user (in enterprise mgr again)